# What is the username and password of the default user in the Live DVD?

Tags: livedvd

I burned the 12.04 version on DVD. Then booted from DVD drive. Eventually I have a choice to install or try. I chose try. Then a dialog came up asking for my username and password. What should I enter?

Answer (score 1):

Try username ubuntu, password blank.
Sometimes this happens, don't know what triggers it.